# Developing Talking Map?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to develop a prototype of a web application that speaks :

When you click on a city (point) it says the city name (Audio files are ready)

I want to use ArcGIS Javascript API. do you have any idea how can I implement this idea ?

Comment: A good starting point is https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app adding audio files should be straight forward

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start with something like this example:

```
require(["esri/map", ...], function(Map, ...) {
  var map = new Map("mapDiv"),
  mapOnLoad = map.on("load", function(){
    map.graphics.on("click", myGraphicsClickHandler);
  });
  map.addLayer(...);

  function myGraphicsClickHandler(evt) {
    alert("User clicked on " + evt.graphic);
  }
});
```

(from [Working with Events](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_events.html))